# How to shift bit inside 2D array

Tags: c

Lets say I had this 2D array in part of my code in c:

```
unsigned short testing[5][3];
```

And then I insert data into it, and lets us monitor that

```
testing[0][0] = 00110010;
testing[0][1] = 01101001;
testing[0][2] = 11100001;
```

And actually if we monitor the first subscript of the array (Monitor using Debug tool)

```
testing[0] = 001100100110100111100001; /*which is combination of 3 second subscript of the array*/
```

And the question is how can I shift 1 bit left of the 2D array

Let's said I wish to get this output

```
Original :
testing[0][0-2] = 001100100110100111100001;
The output I wish :
testing[0][0-2] = 011001001101001111000010;
```

My way to do this, not completed, but I think got another intelligent way to do so asking at here

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        testing[i][j] <<= 1; 
/*I believe here will cause the padding first bit disappear also*/
    }
}
```

If in a normal array(or you can say one dimensional array), I do know can easily done by

```
int a[2];
a[0] <<= 1;
```

But in 2D array, can anyone suggest on it, perhaps got some simple way to shift bit of the first subscript ?

To be clear, I conclude my question, is **there a way to shift first subscript of an 2D array** ?

Comment: You need to manually and explicitly keep track of "spill" bits from the individual elements, and copy them to the correct places in the next (or previous) element. You can't shift each value individually as the "spill" bits will just ignored.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah, I do know that need to keep track it, and the actual array size I use is damn big, so it will cause a lot of process. But from 1D array we can easily shift like a[0] <<= 1, in 2D array does we had method to shift first subscript data like 1D array?

Comment: do endianness matter?

Answer (score 0):

## edit after the clarification that seconf index can be larger than 4

```
void shiftleft(uint16_t *data, size_t nwords)
{
    data[nwords - 1] <<= 1;
    for(size_t index = nwords - 1; index > 0; index--)
    {
        uint32_t tmp;
        
        tmp = data[index - 1] << 1;
        data[index] |= !!(tmp & (1UL << 16));
        data[index - 1] = tmp & 0xffff;
    }
}
```

fr the original question where the second index was `3` you cab use bitfields / union combination.

```
typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint64_t d48: 48;
        uint64_t : 16;
    };
    uint64_t d64;
    uint16_t d16[4];
}Data48;

void shiftleft(uint16_t *data)
{
    Data48 d48;
    d48.d16[0] = *data++;
    d48.d16[1] = *(data+1);
    d48.d16[2] = *(data+2);
    
    d48.d48 <<= 1;
    
    *data++ = d48.d16[0];
    *(data+1) = d48.d16[1];
    *(data+2) = d48.d16[2];
}
```

you will just change it accordingly to your endianness

Comment: I need to use the 2D array. And the array actual size is Uint16 a[200][50]

Comment: @JDC you should explain the actual problem in your question.

Comment: The two writes to the memory location slightly concern me, and I'm not sure the compiler optimiser can get it. It may be necessary to have a "next out" local value, that the compiler will register optimise. Also, for much bigger arrays, you could use the second approach as the middle of a loop-unrolling optimisation, but then you do need to think about endianness.

Comment: Another thing to consider with the second approach is that the original array might be only short aligned, and the processor can be slower or fault for misaligned long operations.

Comment: @GemTaylor Array elements do not pad. Only structure members

Comment: @GemTaylor as OP did not say anything about the platform it is not possible to do any source code optimizations. If it is 8bits AVR the data should be 8 bits. On 64 bit platform there it can done a bit different way as well.

Comment: Yes, I see that you aren't actually performing big reads on the input array, but I suspect that is the way to get best performance.

Answer (score 0):

As an opening remark, it's times like this I wish C supported some of the bit operation that were present on the 8080 / Z80, and are probably available on the x86 as well. In particular, using Z80 parlance the `RLC` instruction.

The relevance to the OP's question is that `RLC` was designed specifically to solve this exact problem: shifting / rotating a multi byte value.  Keeping that in mind, you can achieve the same result using operations available in C.  It's just a little more effort.

```
void arrayshift(unsigned short *array, size_t elementCount)
{
    int carry = 0;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < elementCount; i++)
    {
        // This assumes 8 bit bytes and sizeof(short) == 2. Adjust as needed if this is not the case
        int newCarry = *array >> 15;
        *array = *array << 1 | carry;
        carry = newCarry;
        array++;
    }
}
```

All that said, if your compiler supports it and you're willing to throw portability out the window, you can drop back to assembler and try using instructions available on your target CPU that will do this efficiently.

That's a decision that has to be made on a case by case basis, so I am only going to list it as a possible option, not an answer.

Comment: Yes 8086 and onward do support a rotate with carry operation, so this is certainly an option, if you really need the optimisation.

Comment: You can also look at mmx/msse operations.